# What is the best way to manage certain traits of objects in an array?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, properties, drag-and-drop

I'm using an array for objects that are performing a hitTest on another object, called Chest. Basically I want to drag the array objects into the chest, and when a certain object is in the chest certain functions will run. So to go about it I want to assign each object a "touching" property that is false by default, and true if the array object is touching/"in" the chest, but I'm not sure how.

I'm new to action/javascript and I've heard you can pretty much assign whatever properties you want to any object, but I'm not sure how to go about that and how the properties would be managed.

To add to this, how could I keep track of how many objects in the array are touching the chest?

Any explanations with or without example code would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show us what you've got so far. There's probably a million ways to do what you describe. Also, JavaScript objects are completely dynamic as you describe, but ActionScript objects are not necessarily, so it's not quite the same.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class of the object you want to hittest.(for example, Test)
Add checkHit property or some thing like that.

```
class Test extends MovieClip
{
public var checkHit:Boolean=false;
}
```

In Root class,

push every object into an array.

```
testArray.push(new Test());
```

Now,

You can check hit in EnterFrame event with a loop.

```
for(var i:int=0;i<testArray.length;i++)
{
  if(testArray[i].hitTestObject(chest))
{
    testArray[i].checkhit=true;
/// prefrom your code.
}

}
```

If you want to check no. of objects hitting chest. you can use a global variable.

```
for(var i:int=0;i<testArray.length;i++)
    {
      if(testArray[i].hitTestObject(chest))
    {
        testArray[i].checkhit=true;
          hitCount++;
    /// prefrom your code.
    }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wish I had done it your way, but I'm already so deep in the code I don't want to go back that far to change it. So I  have all the array objects instantiated in an object class that represents the scene that the "Tests" and the chest are going to appear in, called ChestScene. I would like to call this class directly from my main method, so in the constructor I just wrote: ChestScene();, but an error occurs saying an argument was expected. How can I just add that class/object (or any object, for that matter,) directly to the stage?